# Split a with this pattern like this using commandline (not python or perl)

Tags: command-line, awk, split

I am looking for a way to split a text file that looks like this:

```
[something1, something2, something3]
{ a lot of things....}
{a lot of things...including [something4, ...].}
[something5, something6, something7]
{ a lot of things....}
{a lot of things...including [something8, ...].}
.. a random number of {....} 
[something8, something8, something8]
{ a lot of things....}
```

Into files that each contain just one entity:

```
file 1:
[something1, something2, something3]
{ a lot of things....}
{a lot of things...including [something4, ...].}

file 2:
[something5, something6, something7]
{ a lot of things....}
{a lot of things...including [something8, ...].}
.. a random number of {....}
```

and so on. I don't want to use python or perl, and I am wondering if I can do this using awk? or some other command line tool. The separator is always a '[' in the beginning of the line, but not in the middle of the line.

Comment: so the 'separator' for each new file/record will always be a `[` char at the beginning of the line? Please update your question if this is correct (and don't extend conversations in comments (please) ). This seem very doable. Good luck.

Comment: edits to comment finished; -)

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl just as you use AWK in the command line, use the `-e` option:

```
perl -e 'print "Hello world\n"'
```

Then you can create a script that does what you want.

Comment: I can do the same thing with python, I just don't want to use perl or python in this case.